# After using git commit -a, how to revert it back

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git undo last commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit)

After using git commit , how can I discard this commit and revert to my original state?

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit

Answer (score 3):

`git reset HEAD^` will undo the last commit, and the changes you made in that commit will be unstaged but still remain.

`git reset HEAD^ --hard` will undo the commit and delete the changes made in the last commit.

Likewise, `git reset HEAD^^` will go back 2 commits.

The [Git Community Book](http://git-scm.com/book) is a great reference for learning to use git.

Answer (score 1):

You can "undo" a commit like this using:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

The files that you changed in the commit will remain modified in your working directory (see `git status`). If you use `git reset --hard HEAD^`, then the changes you made in the most recent commit will additionally be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to discard all changes with no way of going forward, use:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Over here, HEAD is the ID of any of your previous commits. To roll back just one commit, get the commit id using:

```
git log
```

And then use:

```
git reset --hard 13cca2414skfrrrereaaa
```

**13cca2414skfrrrereaaa** - is what the commit id might look like.

Comment: The commit hash of the commit before `HEAD` is aliased as `HEAD^`, which saves you from having to look that up with `git log`. By the way, the hash has an alphabet of `0-1a-f`, so your "id" would be invalid as it uses the characters s,k,f and r.